# JdkDynamicAopProxy takes over 1 minute to start invoke method when proxy of a @Repository annotated bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

## The problem

I'm experiencing a very strange problem when calling the save method on my constructor injected repository bean. I've narrowed down the problem to the JdkDynamicAopProxy which is the first called method visible in intelliJ's frame overview. I put a breakpoint on the first line in invoke method. It takes over a minute to get from the call to the breakpoint. Nothing (visibly) is happening in between these two frames.

## The code

### Controller

```
    @Controller
    class LoginController(private val userRepository: UserRepository, val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder) {

        @PostMapping(value = ["/register"])
        fun register(@RequestParam("mail") mail: String?, @RequestParam("password") pass: String?, model: Model) : ModelAndView
        {
            val modelAndView = ModelAndView("index")
            if (mail == null || mail == "" || pass == null || pass == "") {
                modelAndView.status = HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE;
                return modelAndView
            }
            // IT IS THE NEXT LINE WHICH IS CAUSING THE LONG WAIT...
            userRepository.save(User(email = mail, password = passwordEncoder.encode(pass), newPassword = pass, firstname = "Test", lastname = "Persoon"))
            modelAndView.status = HttpStatus.OK
            return modelAndView

        }
    }
```

### User repository

```
    @Repository
    interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long> {
        fun findByEmail(email: String): User
    }
```

### application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?serverTimezone=GMT%2B1&useSSL=FALSE&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    spring.datasource.username=username
    spring.datasource.password=password
    spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
    spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5
    spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=Connections

    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.database=mysql
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

    spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.xhtml

    logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
    logging.level.com.zaxxer=ERROR
    logging.level.com.jenson=INFO
    logging.level.root=ERROR
    logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

## The frames

From the register:33, loginController
  To the invoke:157, JdkDynamicAopProxy
  It is taking over 1 minute.

I do not seem to be able to enter that one "frame" in between..

[Overview of the last frames during execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6oI2.jpg)

## EDIT: THE SOLUTION IN THE END

### Not the call, but the password encoding was the issue.

The problem was in the BCryptEncoder bean.

```
    fun bCryptEncoder() : PasswordEncoder = BCryptPasswordEncoder(20)
```

Checking in the source code of the BCryptEncoder tells me that 10 is the empty constructor strength. Using empty constructor and method only takes less than a second now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a `passwordEncoder.encode(pass)` on that "slow line". That's why i think this can be the classic "/dev/urandom" problem.

https://ruleoftech.com/2016/avoiding-jvm-delays-caused-by-random-number-generation

If you are running this code from an IDE, make sure that the actual JVM (that runs your program, not your IDE) has this configuration.

Comment: You are a hero! I extracted the encoding of the pw into a variable first. The slow execution is happening over there, and not in the invocation of the repository...

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: It was not the random number generation strategy in the end, but your comment pointed me to the correct solution. (see edit) 
Changing the random generation "strategy" did not make a difference.